# Best audio converter for flac to alac?

Tags: audio, flac, audio-conversion, lossless, alac

I just got a new phone with a lot more space. This means I can put my lossless audio on... trouble is, iTunes doesn't support flac.... There is alac, but I have yet to find a quality converter to convert flac to alac... does anyone know of one?

edit: Sorry, forgot about OS. Windows 8.1

Comment: On what OS would you like to do that? What have you tried yourself? Googling gave me [a nice hit](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23430/x-lossless-decoder) for OSX as a firstresult.

Comment: Whoops, duh sorry, windows 8.1

I've tried a lot of audio converters that support m4a (the extension of alac) but perform a lossy conversion. As I said, I have yet to find a program that performs this operation lossless-y.

Comment: Open you favorite browser, enter the words: "windows flac to alac" and there are really a lot of usefull links...

Comment: Yeah. Did That already. Tried all of them. Most are adware and worthless and the one legitimate one, dbpoweramp, costs quite a bit.

Comment: On Windows you can use foobar2000 and the encoderpack. On Windows, Linux and Mac you can use PowerShell, flac and ffmpeg. Check my post for more details: [Convert music files from FLAC to ALAC](https://www.meziantou.net/convert-music-files-from-flac-to-alac.htm?utm_medium=social&utm_source=superuser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I have yet to find a quality converter to convert flac to alac

[fre:ac](http://www.freac.org/) supports FLAC to ALAC.

[image]

[image]

#### fre:ac

> fre:ac is a free audio converter and CD ripper with support for various popular formats and encoders.
>
> The Core Audio encoder supports AAC and ALAC formats and is available
> on Windows if you have iTunes or QuickTime installed. Unfortunately,
> it can only be used with the 32 bit version of fre:ac as Apple does
> not provide a 64 bit version of the Core Audio framework for Windows,
> yet.
> Source [fre:ac snapshot 20140223](http://www.freac.org/index.php/en/latest-news-mainmenu-2/15-archive/173-freac-20140223)

#### Disclaimer

I am not at all affiliated with [fre:ac](http://www.freac.org/) in any way, I just use it and find that it works for me.

Comment: I wonder if that's only on that snapshot version, I tried free:ac with the regular download and it only had AAC --- no option for ALAC. I'll try this in a bit

Comment: Images added to show encoder location

Comment: ah thanks. Yeap, the standard download doesn't have that option, snapshot does. Thanks for the help and not giving the 'google it' 'advice.'